# Select Query Join select TOP 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have three table here:  `DinasHoHeader`, `DinasHoDetail` and `Employee`.

First I have this Query

```
select a.KodeDinasHeader,c.Nip,DepartmentCode 
from DinasHoHeader a 
left join DinasHoDetail b on a.KodeDinasHeader = b.KodeDinasHeader 
left join employee c on b.Nip = c.Nip
where DepartmentCode = 'IT'
```

and I get this result

```
KodeDinasHeader   Nip        DepartmentCode
DN0000007       1501971           IT
DN0000007       1411517           IT
```

As you can see i get duplicate `KodeDinasHeader`. I know it's because i have different `Nip`. Because i want to just show `KodeDinasHeader` and `DepartmentCode` only. I'm trying to change my query to this

```
SELECT a.KodeDinasHeader,DepartmentCode From DinasHoHeader a 
left join (
select TOP 1 * from DinasHoDetail
) b on a.KodeDinasHeader = b.KodeDinasHeader
left join employee c on b.Nip = c.Nip
where c.DepartmentCode = 'IT'
```

I get empty result. How can i achieve this?

```
KodeDinasHeader     DepartmentCode
    DN0000007            IT
```

Comment: what do you want to do with this? what result do you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
select DISTINCT a.KodeDinasHeader,DepartmentCode 
from DinasHoHeader a 
left join DinasHoDetail b on a.KodeDinasHeader = b.KodeDinasHeader 
left join employee c on b.Nip = c.Nip
where DepartmentCode = 'IT'
```

Note, I've added DISTINCT and removed the Nip column from the select list.

Comment: I forget about distinct . Thanks.

Comment: no problem, could you accept the answer then? Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

when you don't need nip then why join the table employee ?
Nothnig indicate that Dept code belong to which table.

What about this,

```
declare @DeptCode varchar(50)='IT'
select a.KodeDinasHeader,@DeptCode DepartmentCode 
from DinasHoHeader a 
left join DinasHoDetail b on a.KodeDinasHeader = b.KodeDinasHeader -- or inner join
where DepartmentCode = @DeptCode
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your query like this. Note that i have added a TOP 1 so that you don't need to remove any column. but if you dont need "Nip" Column you can remove this

```
select TOP 1 a.KodeDinasHeader,c.Nip,DepartmentCode 
from DinasHoHeader a 
left join DinasHoDetail b on a.KodeDinasHeader = b.KodeDinasHeader 
left join employee c on b.Nip = c.Nip
where DepartmentCode = 'IT
```